# Scrape ASP Sites using perl mechanize

Tags: perl, asp-classic, mechanize

I am trying to scrape a Asp based site.I am using perl Mechanize module to extract source of the page.i basically use regular expressions for scrape sites.

http://www.imathlete.com/events/EventSearch.aspx#SearchResults

but  i cannot see the html contents in the source page. is there any way to extract the content through Perl.i am new for these kind of sites.

Need some guidance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i can view the source using firebug, but i cannot see them in source of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that `WWW::Mechanize` cant understand Javascript and the side is based on javascript (see global.js on their page). Try it with `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` instead.

There are nice examples of using `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` at

- http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox::Examples

Comment: Thank you so much, for your timely responce.i owe you one. :)

Comment: I am struck with the page navigation. 

`<a href="javascript: GoToPage(2);">Next »</a>`

not able to move next page. need help in processing to the next page.